# Extract just the number of edges in a class graphNEL

Tags: r, graph

Using R I have created an graphNEL class (undirected) with nodes and edges. I want to save the numbers that gets printed out when I print the variable which the undirected graph is saved under:

```
graphNEL graph with undirected edges
Number of Nodes = 671
Number of Edges = 4267
```

I tried using the function edgeL(), but the number I get printed out is the number of nodes. I was thinking that I get this number because each gene has its own amount of edges, which is why the output equals the number of nodes. All I want is to save the number of edges in this graph. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the package, however it looks like nodes and edgeL are returned as slots. This means that you should be able to see the data using $ or @ if you save your graphNEL as an object.

```
yourgraphObject@edgeL
```

Comment: OK I get the slots to print out. So x<-yourgraphObject@edgeL Now when I do x[[1]] I get a list of total edges for each gene. The output is $edges
[1] 566 671 842 602

Comment: How can I get the sum of the edges because I can not do sum(x[[1]]) because I get Error in sum(x[[1]]) : invalid 'type' (list) of argument

Comment: Are "566 671 842 602" the values for your edges that you want?  Strange that they would come in all together in a single element, but if that is the case, you could always split them using strsplit(x$edges, " ")[[1]]. Then you will likely have to make them numbers using as.numeric() and then sum. It seems an odd approach though.  Sorry I don't know more about the package or output.